# Python regex filter only specific matched word

Tags: python, regex

I have below lines in a file and want to find the value of version. Though I have set boundary condition it matches all 3 lines. Is there any way I can fetch only the value of 'version' - 12.6.14

```
 'Nov 05 07:45:45 [INFO ] test-version: 12.4',
 'Nov 05 07:56:39 [INFO ] real-version: 12.3X48',
 'Nov 05 08:09:50 [INFO ] version: 12.6.14',
```

I have tried below code using Python2.7 regex:

```
import re

re.findall(r'\bversion: (.*)?\b',data) # \b to match only specific word
# result: ['12.4','12.3X48','12.6.14']

re.search(r'\bversion: (.*)?\b',data).groups() # outputs the first match data.
# result: ('12.4')
```

Sample : https://regex101.com/r/kwqogH/1

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you’re using Python 2?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile my project code is still with python2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `\b`, a word boundary, will match both space and `-`, so all 3 version values match. Try changing to `\s` instead, so it will only match `version` preceded by whitespace:

```
import re

data = """
'Nov 05 07:45:45 [INFO ] test-version: 12.4',
'Nov 05 07:56:39 [INFO ] real-version: 12.3X48',
'Nov 05 08:09:50 [INFO ] version: 12.6.14'
"""
versions = re.findall(r'\sversion: (.*)?\b',data) # \b to match only specific word
print(versions)
```

Output

```
['12.6.14']
```

Note for Python 2.x `print(versions)` should be `print versions`.

Comment: Your answer may be fine in this case, but note that your pattern would not match `version` at the start of the line/input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen agreed. But there's no evidence that this would be the case for OP.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the regex pattern `(?<!\S)version: (\S+)\b`:

```
data = """'Nov 05 07:45:45 [INFO ] test-version: 12.4',
'Nov 05 07:56:39 [INFO ] real-version: 12.3X48',
'Nov 05 08:09:50 [INFO ] version: 12.6.14'"""

versions = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)version: (\S+)\b', data)
print(versions)
```

This prints:

```
['12.6.14']
```

Comment: This does have the benefit of matching `version` if it's at the beginning of the line.